# Elasticsearch ERROR not enough master nodes discovered during pinging

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

```
 # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration ========================= 
#cluster.name: my-application 
node.name: node-1 
node.master: true 
node.data: true  
network.host: 172.31.24.193 
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:["172.31.24.193","172.31.25.87","172.31.23.237"]
```

#### node-2 elasticsearch.yml configuration

```
  # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration ========================= 
#cluster.name: my-application 
node.name: node-2 
node.master: true 
node.data: true  
network.host: 172.31.25.87 
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:["172.31.24.193","172.31.25.87","172.31.23.237"]
```

#### node-3 elasticsearch configuration

```
  # ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration ========================= 
#cluster.name: my-application 
node.name: node-3 
node.master: true 
node.data: true  
network.host: 172.31.23.237 
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:["172.31.24.193","172.31.25.87","172.31.23.237"]
```

**Error description**: I have installed an `ec2-discovery` plugin. I am passing AWS access key and secret key and endpoint in the elastic keystore.

I am using latest elastic search 6.2. I have started all the nodes on amazon ec2 instances. I have three instances of ec2.
I am getting the error on all the three nodes like this

```
[node-2] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[Candidate{node={node-2}{TpI8T4GBShK8CN7c2ruAXw}{DAsuqCnISsuiw6BGvqrysA}{172.31.25.87}{172.31.25.87:9300}, clusterStateVersion=-1}]], but needed [2]), pinging again
```

Answer (score 2):

First,
to use ec2-discovery, you need to have this in your elasticsearch.yml:
   `discovery.zen.hosts_provider: ec2`
and remove the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`. 
 please check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/discovery-ec2-usage.html 

 The idea of ec2-discovery is not to hardcode the nodes IPs in the config file, but rather auto 'discover' them.

Second, 
the error you've provided shows that the nodes are not able to ping each other, make sure you set a rule in your security group to allow this. In the InBound tab, add a new rule:

Type: All TCP

Source: your security group id (sg-xxxxxx)